# if limit of integral of sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)$ is 0. does it necessary that $f_{n}(x)$ converge at some point?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_{n}(x) : [0,1] \rightarrow [0, \infty )$  such that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_ {0}^{1}  f_{n}(x) dx  = 0 $ but there does not exist any $ x \in [0,1]$ for which the sequence $f_{n}(x)$ converges?

my attempt: since integral converge to 0 so for given $ \epsilon > 0$ there is positive integer $N $  such that $\int_ {0}^{1}  f_{n}(x) dx < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$. Now from here i can say  $f_{n}(x) < \epsilon $ for all $n > N$ on some positive measure subset of [0,1]. Can anyone help me out from here? I believe that no such function exist. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence of your "attempt" is wrong. Having a small integral does not imply small values everywhere. Imagine i continuous function with a narrow tall spike. If it's narrow enough it can be as tall as you wish and still have an area as small as you wish.

Now construct your sequence so that the functions $f_n$ have their spikes at different places in the unit interval.

Edit in response to comment.

The function with this graph has integral $1/n$ (the area of the triangle).

[image]

Now let $a= a_n$ run through an enumeration of the rational numbers. The functions $f_n$ will have arbitrarily high peaks as close as you wish to any $x$.

(In fact, simpler functions will do. Use the same picture with base interval $a \pm 1/n$ and triangle height $1$. Near any $x$ you can find peaks as near both $0$ and $1$ as you like. I don't want to redraw and rescan the picture.)

Comment: can you explain little more?

Comment: @CHOUDHARYbhimsen See my edit.